# JavaScript use background image for multiple elements without downloading each time

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game engine in JavaScript and want to let users uplaod images / select image URLs for object sprites. I'm letting the user create 'blueprint' objects, that are duplicated every time an 'object instance' is created.

Is it possible to use the same image data as the blueprint objects image, for the newly created elements, without downloading the image again? I've looked into using canvases, but can't work out if it's possible to use them to somehow transfer the data from one to the other without downloading images again.

Comment: Are you able to use css/html? This way you could store the image as background-image and just apply the class to the object.

Comment: If you use an image with same name and same url your browser will load it once and then load it from cache if cache expire time is not 0.

Comment: You mean using same image multiple times for one user?

Comment: I mean basically duplicate an object and hopefully use the image data from one object for the new one, rather than downloading the image again.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will store the image first time it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your engine is running on web browsers? If so, even though each object has it's own image, that image will load from the browser's cache so no actual "loading" will take place. That is to say no network call (or lag). I think each image will be a separate image though.

You could pass a single instance of the "blueprint" image to to all your object instances. That way they will all be sharing the same instance.